# jquery mobile button text shadow

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

i need to change the color of the button text shadow on hover, but i can find where in the css

[image: the image]

The "User Details" has a black shadow, but the text in the phone does not, which css class can i change to fix this?

Comment: Hover on mobile? (Can or can't?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 .ui-link-inherit{
     text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
 }
```

You should check the class on your browser inspector, I'm not sure if it is the 'ui-link-inherit' class. And you should use the same css as the title..

Comment: I'm going to one up this but - the change above is global to your JQM. You may want to add a custom class and then tie into it to do it for specific areas.